# Need to use $add and $gt in remove using mgo (Golang && MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I'm using  Golang as my backend and MongoDB as the database for my web application. I'm in need of adding two values and check if the value in the database is greater than the added value and if it is, I need to remove the row from the MongoDB.
The code which I wrote is as follows

```
err, err1 := c.RemoveAll(bson.M{
        "currenttime": bson.M{
            "$gt": bson.M{
                "$add": []interface{}{time.Now().Unix(),"100"},
            },
        },
     })
```

FYI: I wrote the sample code for MongoDB but this is not working as well

```
db.Collection.remove(
   {currenttime:{
        $gt:{
                $add:[100,100]
             }
              }
    }
 )
```

Please let me know if this is possible. And please give me any alternative way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: can you post how your document looks like ? from what i am seeing your approach is wrong because $add is something that you use with aggregation, you cannot simply use it with normal CRUD queries.

Comment: you cannot use $add normally.... it's only for aggregation part dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- If you need to remove rows with field e.g. `time > t + 10` from the MongoDB, you do't need `$add`, you may use:

```
info, err := c.RemoveAll(bson.M{"time": bson.M{"$gt": t + 10}})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Here is the working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true) // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    c := session.DB("test").C("Model")
    c.DropCollection()
    t := time.Now().UTC().Unix()
    err = c.Insert(
        &Model{bson.NewObjectId(), "n1", t},
        &Model{bson.NewObjectId(), "n2", t + 50},
        &Model{bson.NewObjectId(), "n3", t + 100},
        &Model{bson.NewObjectId(), "n4", t + 150})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r := []Model{}
    err = c.Find(nil).All(&r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r)

    info, err := c.RemoveAll(bson.M{"time": bson.M{"$gt": t + 10}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(info)

    r2 := []Model{}
    err = c.Find(nil).All(&r2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r2)
}

type Model struct {
    ID   bson.ObjectId `json: "_id,omitempty" bson: "_id,omitempty"`
    Name string        `json: "name" bson: "name"`
    Time int64         `json: "time" bson: "time"`
}
```

output:

```
[{ObjectIdHex("57f7354cc3176906c0ca7516") n1 1475818828} {ObjectIdHex("57f7354cc3176906c0ca7517") n2 1475818878} {ObjectIdHex("57f7354cc3176906c0ca7518") n3 1475818928} {ObjectIdHex("57f7354cc3176906c0ca7519") n4 1475818978}]
&{0 3 3 <nil>}
[{ObjectIdHex("57f7354cc3176906c0ca7516") n1 1475818828}]
```

---

2- For `$add`, see:
[Query where sum of two fields is less than given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882159/query-where-sum-of-two-fields-is-less-than-given-value)
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i propose. You can do it in two steps rather then in one.

first find all the entries that matches you delete criteria. Then delete those matching entries using remove() query.

The below query will return all the documents with currentTime greater then 200.(add 100 to 100).

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { currentTime: 1, current_time:{ $gt: [ "$currentTime", { $add: [ 100,100 ] } ] } }}
   ]
)
```

i created a sample collection with the following data :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714f0b30252798d8a2988"), "currentTime" : 1000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714f4b30252798d8a2989"), "currentTime" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714f7b30252798d8a298a"), "currentTime" : 150 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714fcb30252798d8a298b"), "currentTime" : 1250 }
```

and the result of the above query on this collection is :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714f0b30252798d8a2988"), "currentTime" : 1000, "current_time" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714f4b30252798d8a2989"), "currentTime" : 100, "current_time" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714f7b30252798d8a298a"), "currentTime" : 150, "current_time" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f714fcb30252798d8a298b"), "currentTime" : 1250, "current_time" : true }
```

as you can see from the results that documents which has currentTime as 100 and 150 have returned false since they are less then 200.

Answer (score 0):

***Now this is the way to remove your documents*** :

**What you were doing :**

> you cannot simply use $add as this operator only works with aggregate system

**What you should do actually**

1. Get All Records to be deleted using Aggregate methodology
2. Run a loop over them and remove

***Example***:

`var cursor = db.Collection.aggregate([
 { $match: { currenttime: { $gt:{ $add:[100,100] }}}}
]);
cursor.forEach(function (doc){
    db.Collection.remove({"_id": doc._id});
});`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample code, I can observe that you use MongoDB `remove` command to filter only values of field `currenttime` greater than a particular value.

If you intend to delete certain documents after they passed certain time, you should check out MongoDB [Time To Live](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/glossary/#term-ttl) feature. Where you can [Expire Data from Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/expire-data/)

For example, you can specify :

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "field_containing_time": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

To expire any documents from a collection after one hour. See also [TTL Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-ttl/)

Although this answer contain no Golang related code, if this is what you are trying to do in the big picture, it may be beneficial for your use case.